# SecItemAdd or SecItemDelete result -50 (errSecParam), Delphi XE for IOS, MacOS

Tags: ios, macos, delphi, rsa, keychain

I am trying to write IOS (MacOS) client for my server application on windows, need to implement RSA (RSA 2048bit) encryption.

I get modulus and exponent from server (on windows side) and parse it to NSDATA in BER format. A am already have Java client for Android and its work great.

But when I try to use SecItemAdd it return error -50 (errSecParam One or more parameters passed to the function were not valid.), my code in Delphi XE, test on MacOS Yosemite with last XCode

```
var
  peerName: NSString;
  peerTag, RSAKeyNS: NSDATA;
  peerPublicKeyAttr: TNSMutableDictionary;
  persistPeer, CFDictionaryRef1: Pointer; 
begin
  peerName := StrToNSStr('Test Public Key');
  peerTag := peerName.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);

  RSAKeyStream. 
  RSAKeyNS := TNSData.Wrap(TNSData.Alloc.initWithBytes(RSAKeyStream.Memory,Cardinal(RSAKeyStream.Size)));
  RSAKeyStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  b1 := 48; // SEQUENCE  $30
  RSAKeyStream.Write(b1, SizeOf(b1));
  //...
  //... write PublicKey data in BER code to stream

  peerPublicKeyAttr := TNSMutableDictionary.Create;

  kSecClass := StrToNSStr('kSecClass');
  kSecClassKey := StrToNSStr('kSecClassKey');
  kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA := StrToNSStr('kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA');
  kSecAttrKeyType := StrToNSStr('kSecAttrKeyType');
  kSecAttrApplicationTag := StrToNSStr('kSecAttrApplicationTag');
  kSecValueData := StrToNSStr('kSecValueData');
  kSecReturnPersistentRef := StrToNSStr('kSecReturnPersistentRef');

  peerPublicKeyAttr.setValue((kSecClassKey as ILocalObject).GetObjectID, kSecClass);
  peerPublicKeyAttr.setValue((kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA as ILocalObject).GetObjectID, kSecAttrKeyType);
  peerPublicKeyAttr.setValue((peerTag as ILocalObject).GetObjectID, kSecAttrApplicationTag);
  peerPublicKeyAttr.setValue((RSAKeyNS as ILocalObject).GetObjectID, kSecValueData);
  peerPublicKeyAttr.setValue(TNSNumber.OCClass.numberWithBool(True), kSecReturnPersistentRef);

  persistPeer := nil;
  CFDictionaryRef1 := (peerPublicKeyAttr as ILocalObject).GetObjectID; 
  sanityCheck := SecItemAdd(CFDictionaryRef1, persistPeer); 
  sanityCheck - -50 /// error
end;
```

Yes, I understand that I can have error in KeyData, therefore I test it on SecItemDelete function, it is more simple, and I get the same error -50.

```
  peerPublicKeyAttr.setValue((kSecClassKey as ILocalObject).GetObjectID, kSecClass);
  peerPublicKeyAttr.setValue((kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA as ILocalObject).GetObjectID, kSecAttrKeyType);
  peerPublicKeyAttr.setValue((peerTag as ILocalObject).GetObjectID, kSecAttrApplicationTag);

  CFDictionaryRef1 := (peerPublicKeyAttr as ILocalObject).GetObjectID; 
  sanityCheck := SecItemDelete(CFDictionaryRef1); 
  sanityCheck - -50 /// error
```

May be problem in NSData - peerTag, i try pass it as pointer to Data peerTag.Bytes or @peerTag but I have access violation for this case.

```
Functions
const
  libSecurity = '/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security';
function SecItemAdd(ApeerPublicKeyAttr: Pointer; persistPeer: Pointer): OSStatus; cdecl; external libSecurity name _PU + 'SecItemAdd';
function SecItemDelete(ApeerPublicKeyAttr: Pointer): OSStatus; cdecl; external libSecurity name _PU + 'SecItemAdd';
```

I try to search answer but not find it.
I Use IPhone emulator on MacOS.
Please help)

Comment: problem a little fixed, by changing contant kSecClass := StrToNSStr('class'); - fixed